# iPhone one finger scaling gesturerecognizer

Tags: iphone, uigesturerecognizer, image-scaling

I want to handle scaling and rotation of a view with one corner in that view. I found one tutorial for the rotation.
https://github.com/kirbyt/KTOneFingerRotationGestureRecognizer

It makes custom UIGesturRecognizer for rotation using atan2f function.
But there is nothing i could find for scaling. Can anybody tell me which is similar math function for scaling or any tutorial help for this purpose.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

-(void)oneFingerGesture:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
    if ([recognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan)
    {
        //rotation
        deltaAngle = atan2([recognizer locationInView:holderView.superview].y-holderView.center.y, [recognizer locationInView:holderView.superview].x-holderView.center.x);
        startTransform = holderView.transform;
        //resize
        prevPoint = [recognizer locationInView:holderView.superview];
        [holderView setNeedsDisplay];

```
}
else if ([recognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged)
{
    //rotation
    float ang = atan2([recognizer locationInView:holderView.superview].y - holderView.center.y, [recognizer locationInView:holderView.superview].x - holderView.center.x);
    float angleDiff = deltaAngle - ang;
    holderView.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(startTransform, -angleDiff);

    //resize
    CGPoint point = [recognizer locationInView:holderView.superview];
    float wChange = 0.0, hChange = 0.0, value=0.0;

    wChange = (point.x - prevPoint.x);
    hChange = (point.y - prevPoint.y);

    CGFloat radians = atan2f(holderView.transform.b, holderView.transform.a);
    CGFloat degrees = radians * (180 / M_PI);

    if (degrees<=0 && degrees>=-90) {
        value=wChange;
    }
    else if (degrees<=-90 && degrees>=-180){
        value=-hChange;
    }
    else if (degrees<=180 && degrees>=90){
        value=-wChange;
    }
    else if (degrees<=90 && degrees>=0){
        value=hChange;
    }

    holderView.bounds = CGRectMake(holderView.bounds.origin.x, holderView.bounds.origin.y, holderView.bounds.size.width + (value), holderView.bounds.size.height + (value));
    imageview.frame = CGRectMake(12, 12, holderView.bounds.size.width-24, holderView.bounds.size.height-27);
    View_marqueRotate.frame =CGRectMake(holderView.bounds.size.width-25, holderView.bounds.size.height-25, 25, 25);
    View_marqueClose.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 25, 25);

    prevPoint = [recognizer locationInView:holderView.superview];
    [holderView setNeedsDisplay];


}
else if ([recognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)
{
    //rotation
    deltaAngle = atan2([recognizer locationInView:holderView.superview].y-holderView.center.y, [recognizer locationInView:holderView.superview].x-holderView.center.x);
    startTransform = holderView.transform;

    //resize
    prevPoint = [recognizer locationInView:holderView.superview];
    [holderView setNeedsDisplay];

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Find the below Tutorials to Scale the Images.

https://github.com/ardalahmet/SSPhotoCropperViewController

https://github.com/iosdeveloper/ImageCropper

[Download](http://code4app.com/down/id/507e21c36803fa4667000000)

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code you will be able to rotate, scale and move of any object:

https://github.com/erica/iphone-3.0-cookbook-/tree/master/C08-Gestures/14-Resize%20And%20Rotate/